# Can someone help me with this gradle error on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

im getting the error this error when i try to run my my project on android studio. can someone help me?

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         25.1.1
         25.1.0
         25.0.1
         25.0.0
         24.2.1
         + 22 more
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/
         file:/C:/Users/EDUdigital/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/EDUdigital/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/EDUdigital/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/
     Required by:
         AppTraining:app:unspecified
```

Comment: post your app build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as an example:

My `build.gradle`, compiles the `SDK` to `API 25`, thus it'll needs the `25+` version of the dependency.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

The version depends on the API version you're compiling to. I would specify a specific version rather than doing `.+` so in your case you could do `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the "Android Support Repository" in your SDK Manager. if that's not the case You need to change the version of your dependency in gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You Can solve your problem by doing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTqK4.png)
Here click Migrater to AndroidX and click on the red lines where there are problems see the solutions provided by the android like updating to newer version, importing class.